# Aligning data to be imported in Database

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have file that contain 44 columns. The problem is the there's `,` on one field. I would like to divide that data on the particular column and put it on the next column of it.

Raw:

```
122|abc |ds,we       |||wrqg
145|dw  |ett,335     |||nxd
166|rotl|qqqp,eoepepe|||ge
776|gge |022         |||pp
039|pot |011a        |||lot
```

Expected output:

```
122|abc |ds  |we||wrqg
145|dw  |ett |335||nxd
166|rotl|qqqp|eoepepe||ge
776|gge |022 |||pp
039|pot |011a|||lot
```

With this output, the data will be imported on the correct field on my Database table.

I've tried this code but the data will add a new column.

```
`awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(",", "|", $3); print }' file`
```

Really need your help guys!

Comment: Is the field with the comma always in the third column? Is the column after such fields always empty?

Comment: The important is that on the 3rd column, i need to separate the record with comma. And YES, the next column is always blank.

Comment: It is because the data after the `comma` is assigned on the next column of my table in database, that's why the next column is always blank.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 comma in that 3rd column or is it always 0 or 1 comma?

Comment: 0 or 1 comma, Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { split($3, a, ","); $3 = a[1]; $4 = a[2]; print }' file
122|abc |ds|we       ||wrqg
145|dw  |ett|335     ||nxd
166|rotl|qqqp|eoepepe||ge
776|gge |022         |||pp
039|pot |011a        |||lot
```

What I'm doing here is that I split the 3rd field on commas.  This assigns the split-up bits into the array `a` as separate array elements. I then set the 3rd field to the first bit, and the 4th field to the second bit (`a[1]` and `a[2]` respectively).

This assumes that the 3rd original field only ever contains a single comma (or no comma at all).  If it contains more than one comma, you would lose whatever data comes after the second comma.

Comment: If you make it `split($3,a,/,/)>1{$3=a[1]; $4=a[2]} 1` then it won't change $4 unless $3 contains a `,`. I know the OP said the next column is blank but that way you don't care.

Comment: You really save me @Kusalananda. Thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach, telling `awk` to use either `|` or `,` as delimiter, and deciding what to print on how many fields are present in that row:

```bsh
awk -F '[|,]' '
    BEGIN {OFS="|"}
    NF==6 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
    NF==7 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6,$7}
' <(tr -d ' ' < file)
```

Output:

```
122|abc|ds|we||wrqg
145|dw|ett|335||nxd
166|rotl|qqqp|eoepepe||ge
776|gge|022|||pp
039|pot|011a|||lot
```

As I don't really get the use of spaces in your in- and output, I just removed all of them ...

Comment: This can't be use because on the other column their might be a comma, i just need to focus on the comma on the specific column which is column 3

Comment: you should include all relevant information in the question ...

Comment: Apology for that matter.